# Magento2 CE Can't use model custom extension attributes

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I am trying to learn Magento 2 (community edition v.2.3.4) but I seem to have hit a brick wall while dealing with extension attributes. I did everything according to the documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html 
and https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-external-links but the generated by magento compiler code (class name "AffiliateMemberExtension") does not have the method to add my custom attribute named "sample".

The exact error message I'm getting from REST endpoint is

```
Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method SimplifiedMagento\\Database\\Api\\Data\\AffiliateMemberExtension::setSample() in \/home\/azumi\/work\/magento2\/app\/code\/SimplifiedMagento\/Attribute\/Model\/Plugin\/CodeAttributeExtension.php:37
```

My full source code is located here: https://gitlab.com/naevus19/my-magento/-/tree/master/app/code/SimplifiedMagento/Attribute

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't know how to debug this further :(

*extension_attributes.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="\SimplifiedMagento\Database\Api\Data\AffiliateMemberInterface">
        <attribute code="sample" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

*di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="\SimplifiedMagento\Database\Api\AffiliateMemberRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="attribute_code_plugin" type="\SimplifiedMagento\Attribute\Model\Plugin\CodeAttributeExtension" />
    </type>
</config>
```

*module.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="SimplifiedMagento_Attribute" setup_version="0.1.0"  />
</config>
```

plugin code CodeAttributeExtension.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: kamil
 * Date: 07.05.20
 * Time: 16:39
 */

namespace SimplifiedMagento\Attribute\Model\Plugin;

use SimplifiedMagento\Database\Api\AffiliateMemberRepositoryInterface;
use \SimplifiedMagento\Database\Api\Data\AffiliateMemberExtensionFactory;
use SimplifiedMagento\Database\Api\Data\AffiliateMemberInterface;
use SimplifiedMagento\Database\Model\AffiliateMember;
use \SimplifiedMagento\Database\Model\AffiliateMemberRepository;

class CodeAttributeExtension
{
    protected $extensionFactory;

    public function __construct(AffiliateMemberExtensionFactory $extensionFactory)
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }

    public function afterGetAffiliateMemberById
    (
        AffiliateMemberRepositoryInterface $subject,
        AffiliateMember $entity
    ) {
        $entity->setCustomAttribute('sample', "Code #" . $entity->getId());
        $extensionAttributes = $entity->getExtensionAttributes();

        if (empty($extensionAttributes)) {
            $extensionAttributes = $this->extensionFactory->create();
        }
        $extensionAttributes->setSample("Code #" . $entity->getId());
        $entity->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $entity;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is behind links, which means it can't be searched by people who have the same question as you in the future. Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: @Joundill Fixed.

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all I will try to set extension attribute by `setData()` method, like:

```
$extensionAttributes->setData('sample', 'Code #' . $entity->getId());
```

and remove first backslash `\SimplifiedMagento` in your *.xml files where you declared your classes and interfaces namespaces.